# Natural extensions of Fary's Theorem?

Tags: general-topology, geometry, graph-theory, geodesic, planar-graphs

When recently reading about the remarkable (but *somewhat* intuitive) [Fary's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%A1ry%27s_theorem), I wondered about natural extensions of it to other spaces, none of which were listed on the Wikipedia page.

It's clear how we define concepts such as planarity in other well-known surfaces, such as tori or Klein Bottles etc., however it is less clear to me how to characterise whether a line is "straight" in a natural sense on tori, etc. So:

- Is there a natural way to characterise straight-ness in other spaces? (I have heard previously of the concept of a "geodesic", but am not at all familiar with it)
- Can we use this to find generalisations of Fary's Theorem in these other spaces?

Comment: If anyone is interested, I read about a way of proving such a thing on a torus, where we embed the torus on the unit square, i.e. there *is* a natural extension to tori. There's a[n unfortunately] terrible version [here](http://bkocay.cs.umanitoba.ca/g&g/articles/Torus.pdf).

Comment: See also [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/122014/108884)